# Привести данные в формат datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть данные о дате совершения покупок в датафрейме.
Хранятся в формате int64.
Выглядят так:

1. 2018100100
2. 2018100100
3. 2019103112
4. 2019103116
5. и.т.д.

Видно что данные представляют с собой год/месяц/день/и час совершения покупки
Нужно привести их к формату datetime format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
Дабы получилось так:

1. 2018-10-01 00:00:00
2. 2018-10-01 00:00:00
3. 2019-10-31 12:00:00
4. 2019-10-31 16:00:00

Пример кода:
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

[image: Исходный формат колонки date]

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

используйте метод to_datetime со своим форматом:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([2018100100, 2018100100, 2019103112, 2019103116], columns=["date"])
```

```
         date
0  2018100100
1  2018100100
2  2019103112
3  2019103116
```

вот таким образом:

```
df["converted"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y%m%d%H")
```

```
         date           converted
0  2018100100 2018-10-01 00:00:00
1  2018100100 2018-10-01 00:00:00
2  2019103112 2019-10-31 12:00:00
3  2019103116 2019-10-31 16:00:00
```